# include sass to pug

Tags: html, sass, jade, pug

У меня есть `page.pug`, в котором я хочу делать  `include components/footer/footer.pug`, внутри `footer.pug` имеет такой вид:

```
style
    include _footer.sass

footer
// прочая разметка
```

Проблема в том, что стили не подтягиваются. Только хтмл разметка.
Расположение файлов:

```
/pages.pug
/components/footer/footer.pug
/components/footer/_footer.sass
```

Что я делаю не так? Как правильно инклюдить паг? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sass` нужно предварительно скомпилировать в `CSS`:

```
style
     include ../css/style.css
```